# How to replicate statistical significance in STEPAR method of SAS Proc FORECAST?

Tags: sas, autoregressive-models

This is basically a trend model + Autoregressive Error model

Figuring out the coefficients for the AR model is just a straightforward application of Yule-Walker equations. However, not sure about how they evaluate statistical significance of these coefficients. Anyone have an idea of how to calculate the p-values for these estimated coefficients?

```
proc forecast data=sashelp.usecon interval=month
          method=stepar trend=2 lead=12
          out=out outfull outest=est;
id date;
var durables nondur;
where date >= '1jan80'd;
run;
```

Comment: It would be better to convert this to `proc arima` to view the p-values directly. Can you post your code?

Comment: @StuSztukowski, I posted the code I'm using in the OP. It's really just an example constructed by SAS